# prevent div inside of table from expanding beyond parent's size

Tags: html, css, overflow, html-table

I'm working on a page where I need a table which will horizontally-scroll inside of a parent div if the table becomes wider than its parent.

Unfortunately, the platform I'm building this on places my code within a parent table cell, which breaks this. It seems that even if I put my table inside of a div (and set `overflow-x: scroll` on that div), the parent table cell inserted by the platform will expand past the size of the page to contain the children.

I've made a fiddle of what this looks like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3e9esL5/

... and a fiddle of what I *want* this to look like here (sans outer table):
http://jsfiddle.net/4budchj6/

Clearly removing the outer table fixes this problem, but unfortunately due to the platform I'm working on I can't do that. It's also best if I can avoid applying styles to the outer table, as that markup isn't under my control.

Is there any way I can style this the way I want without changing the outer table's markup or style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `overflow-x` you have to specify `max-width` (or `width`) too.

If you write something like this:

```
.flex-table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

You will have a table never bigger than `250px`, with horizontal scrollbar showed only if needed.

Comment: Without knowing the width of the containing cell, is there any way I could set the max width to be equal to the width of the container?

Comment: you could use `width: auto`. In this case if you somehow specify parent width, children will adjust accordingly to that width.